# Array push with $_SESSION and $_POST not working

Tags: php, arrays, session, post

So I'm kind of new to PHP, otherwise I wouldn't be here I guess.
Anyway, I've been trying to practice, and I'm currently building a Shoutbox.
However, I can't seem to save anything other than the previous shout. They seem to keep replacing each other at the first entry of the array. I tried everything I could think of, and it might be something I did with the HTML form name, but I'm clueless.
So, here goes, I hope someone has a lightbulb moment when looking at it.

This is the PHP:

```
session_start();

$_SESSION['shout'] = array();
array_push($_SESSION['shout'], $_POST['shout'][0]);
$arrayPlace = count($_SESSION['shout']);

foreach($_SESSION['shout'] as $key => $value)
    {
    $arrayPlace+=1;
    echo $arrayPlace;

    }


?>
```

And the HTML:

```
<form action="<?php $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>" method="post">  
    <h2>Shoutbox Kevin</h2>  
<label for="text">Vul hier uw Shout! in:</label></br>
<input type="text" name="shout[]"/></br>
<input type="submit" value="Verzenden" />
</form>
```

Comment: Oh and yeah I tried the $_POST['shout'] without the [0] key as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is: every time you post a shout, you re-initialize the shout-array:

```
$_SESSION['shout'] = array();
```

You shoud do that only once (if it doesn't exists):

```
if (!isset($_SESSION['shout'])) {
    $_SESSION['shout'] = array();
}
```

BTW: You can leave both the `[0]` in `$_POST['shout'][0]` and the `[]` in `name="shout[]"` away if you let users only shout one message at a time.

Comment: You sir, are a genius. My eternal gratitude!

Comment: You are aware that sessions aren't the best way to store shoutbox-contents? If you're only playing around with sessions it's ok off course, but otherwise: contents will only be visible for you, if you open a new browser contents will be gone (or actually, it has its own shout-array).

Comment: Ah, yeah I was just looking for an alternative way to store them temporarily. Otherwise I suppose I should use SQL with a user/shout database..